# Extracting separate tables from a database

Tags: python, sql, database, ms-access, extract

I have 12 075 400 entries on my MS Access database. Each entry corresponds to an employee. There are total of 270 employees, i.e. each employee has multiple entries. There are other multiple columns for each employee such as salary, location etc.

I wanted to create 270 separate tables corresponding to each employee in the same database. The employees are entered into the database as 1, 2, 3, 4....till 270 with all their other details in other columns.

I tried writing an SQL query for that, but its not working. How can I extract multiple tables out of this database to create separate 270 tables for each employee? I was also thinking of using a relational database, but don't know how will it work!

I am also allowed to use python for the same. If anyone can suggest how to do it using python that will be great too.

Comment: *I wanted to create 270 separate tables corresponding to each employee in the same database.*...why? All such data is retrievable by queries. And with 12 million records in one table you might not want to extended resources in hundreds of redundant tables.

Comment: You really *don't* want to do this. If you tell us what you actually want to achieve, there will be a way with a query. But before you ask a new question, please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). Sample data and expected result is much more useful than a textual description.

Comment: Are those 12,075,400 entries all stored in one table? If so,it's about time to split up that table into other tables (1 table per entity).

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO MyNewTable(ID, Name)
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Name FROM MyBigOldTable
```

Where MyBigOldTable is your existing table.

`Distinct` will ensure each combination returned is unique, so only include columns that are unique to the employee master record, not the "transactional" values.

Edit

I should have said that this is assuming you have already created the new table with

```
CREATE MyNewTable(ID int, Name varchar)
```

Not sure about Access, but you should be able to skip this step by doing

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Name
INTO MyNewTable
FROM MyBigOldTable
```

and if that doesn't work, try

```
SELECT *
INTO MyNewTable
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, Name
    FROM MyBigOldTable
) as Foo
```